# App Engine deploy with Go libraries

Tags: google-app-engine, go, gcloud

I'm new on Google App Engine. And, I'm getting an issue that I can't solve.

I've a very simple app (developped in Go) like this :

```
main/
|   model/
|   |   user.go
|   main.go
|   app.yaml
```

These are the imports of main.go :

```
import (
    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)
```

My code works well when I run it locally.

But, when I try to publish it on my Google App Engine instance, I receive this error :

```
$ gcloud app deploy

You are about to deploy the following services:
 - <MY_APP_ENGINE_URL> (from [<MY_LOCAL_YAML_PATH>])
 Deploying to URL: [<MY_APP_ENGINE_URL>]

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  Y

Beginning deployment of service [default]...
Some files were skipped. Pass `--verbosity=info` to see which ones.
You may also view the gcloud log file, found at
[<LOCAL_APP_ENGINE_LOG>].
File upload done.
Updating service [default]...failed.                                                                                                                                                             
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Deployment contains files that cannot be compiled: Compile failed:
2017/05/27 14:48:24 go-app-builder: build timing: 5×compile (301ms total), 0×link (0s total)
2017/05/27 14:48:24 go-app-builder: failed running compile: exit status 2

main.go:4: can't find import: "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
```

What did I do wrong ?

**EDIT :**
This is the content of my app.yaml file :

```
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: _go_app
```

Answer (score 1):

App Engine environment doesn't contain your dependencies, you can add an script to do a go get ... for each one but it's too hacky and Go has a solution for that, we can save our dependencies in a **vendor** folder on the root of our project.

**Quick solution**:

```
# Instal godep:
go get -v -u github.com/tools/godep

cd your/project/path
godep save
```

Now try to deploy again, you'll see a **vendor** folder in your project, don't remove it and add it to your git source, that folder contains all your third party dependencies like your httprouter (it's my favorite :) )

Note You can use other tools to save your dependencies

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

It created me 2 folders Godeps and vendor (which contains the content of my dependencies); but I still receive the same error from App Engine :
main.go:4: can't find import: "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"

Comment: are you including everything in the app.yaml ?

Comment: Hi, I added the content of my app.yaml in edit :)
Reading the response of @Ain, it's seems that GoDeps can't help me. Is it true ?

Comment: not sure what's the exact Go version of app engine, but in case of an old one you should try to `export GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=1`, also the problem looks like a app engine problem, try to find how to include all files and sub-folders

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the `gcloud` tool, but back in the day when `goapp` was the tool you had to create `github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter` (with the lib's source in it, of course) directly under you'r `main` and then deploy.

AFAIK the App Engine's go version is currently 1.6 which means that while the vendoring is on by default, it can be switched off - perhaps thats the case and thats why @Yandry Pozo's suggestion doesn't work.